# Convert decimal (2.75) to time (2:45)

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a double like 2.75, is there a way in .Net to format it as '2:45'

If it is for example, 2.75555555555, it should round it to the nearest minute.
I would not mind coding this myself, but I am wondering if .Net can. I checked ToString but did not find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852305/c-sharp-string-format-for-hours-and-minutes-from-decimal) would give a starting point?

Comment: Look into TimeSpan.FromHours

Comment: Check this [SO Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5852329/125551) for similar conversion

Comment: Yeah, never used it yet. And why so rude?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use TimeSpan and its ToString formatter:

```
TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2.75);
string output = timespan.ToString("h\\:mm");
```

For example

```
TimeSpan.FromHours(2.75555).ToString("h\\:mm")
```

outputs

2:45

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Your answer and Sten's answer probably got down-voted because you didn't use `TimeSpan`. Not sure if it's enough of a reason but that's my suspicion.

Comment: This will not work if the value entered is more than 24 hours.  Say the value entered is 26.3, it will say 2:18.  I simple fix I used was TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2.75);  string output = $"{(timespan .Days * 24) + timespan .Hours}h {timespan .Minutes}m";