# Powershell Format Duration as Hours and Minutes

Tags: powershell, date-formatting, duration

I am trying to format the string output of a TimeSpan as `$h Hours $m Minutes`, accounting for pluralization. Right now, I have the below code which works pretty well; however, when it encounters a TimeSpan of less than an hour it will display it as `0 $m minutes`.

```
Function FormatDuration ([TimeSpan]$Duration) {
    [string]$DurationStr = [math]::floor($Duration.TotalMinutes/60).ToString()
    if ([math]::floor($Duration.TotalMinutes/60) -eq 1) {
        $DurationStr = $DurationStr+" hour"
    } elseif ([math]::floor($Duration.TotalMinutes/60) -ne 0) {
        $DurationStr = $DurationStr+" hours"
    }
    if ($Duration.Minutes -eq 1){
        $DurationStr = $DurationStr+" "+$Duration.Minutes+" minute"
    # Does not display minutes if value is 0
    } elseif ($Duration.Minutes -ne 0) {
        $DurationStr = $DurationStr+" "+$Duration.Minutes+" minutes"
    }
    return $DurationStr
}
```

I tried finding if someone else has solved this problem, but the closest I was able to find was zuallauz' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505362/7803239) in [this C# thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852305/c-sharp-string-format-for-hours-and-minutes-from-decimal).

Unfortunately, it seems TimeSpans behave differently  in Powershell where they will display days and hours separately, meaning a TimeSpan of 25 hours and 45 minutes will be stored as:

```
New-TimeSpan -Hours 25 -Minutes 45

Days              : 1
Hours             : 1
Minutes           : 45
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 927000000000
TotalDays         : 1.07291666666667
TotalHours        : 25.75
TotalMinutes      : 1545
TotalSeconds      : 92700
TotalMilliseconds : 92700000
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with how to solve this issue? My first thoughts are to separate processing of hours and minutes and then to concatenate them at the end instead of at each if-else statement.

### Edit:

With the help of Sambardo's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49659941/7803239), I was able to create the following function:

```
Function FormatDuration ([TimeSpan]$Duration) {
    $h = $Duration.Days * 24 + $Duration.Hours
    $m = $Duration.Minutes

    switch ($h) {
        0 {$HourStr=$null}
        1 {$HourStr="$h hour"}
        {$_ -ge 1} {$HourStr="$h hours"}
    }
    switch ($m) {
        0 {$MinuteStr=$null}
        1 {$MinuteStr="$m minute"}
        {$_ -ge 1} {$MinuteStr="$m minutes"}
    }
    if ($HourStr -gt 0 -and $MinuteStr -gt 0) {
        [String]$DurationStr=$HourStr+" "+$MinuteStr
    } else {
        $DurationStr=$HourStr+$MinuteStr
    }

    return $DurationStr
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something about your question, but why not just turn days to hours and then check if hours is greater than 0 to adjust your string?

```
$TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 45
$h = $TimeSpan.Days * 24 + $TimeSpan.Hours
$m = $TimeSpan.Minutes
if($h -gt 0){"$h hours $m minutes"}
else{"$m minutes"}
```

Comment: Huh, that is a great idea converting days to hours and then adding the remaining hours. Only thing missing from your answer is the scenario where it's an even hour, but that should be simple enough to test for. I should be able to work with this and create a separate pluralization function that will format hour(s) and minute(s) correctly.

I'll post my completed function when it's done. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, if this helped solve your problem please mark it as the answer and upvote it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A little annoying to do to make it look pretty how you want it, but this will fulfill your request.

```
$Duration = New-TimeSpan -Hours 25 -Minutes 1
$TotalHours = $Duration.Hours + ( $Duration.Days * 24 )

$String = "$TotalHours Hour"
if ( $TotalHours -gt 1 )
{
    $String += 's'
}
$String += " $($Duration.Minutes) Minute"
if ( $Duration.Minutes -gt 1 )
{
    $String += 's'
}

return $String
```

Returns the value

```
25 Hours 1 Minute
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `else` condition at the end. When floor Duration is not 1 and is not different than zero, the only possible value that left for floor Duration is zero. So in your `else` you can manage zero value by blanking the string.

```
if ([math]::floor($Duration.TotalMinutes/60) -eq 1) {
    $DurationStr = $DurationStr+" hour"
} elseif ([math]::floor($Duration.TotalMinutes/60) -ne 0) {
    $DurationStr = $DurationStr+" hours"
} else {
    $DurationStr = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function FormatDuration ([TimeSpan]$Duration) {
    $DurHours = [math]::floor($Duration.TotalHours)
    $DurMins  = $Duration.Minutes
    if ($DurHours-1){$PlHours='s'} else {$PlHours=''}
    if ($DurMins -1){$PlMins='s'}  else {$PlMins=''}
    return "{0} hour$($PlHours) {1} minute$($PlMins)" -f $DurHours,$DurMins
}

FormatDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours 25 -Minutes 45)
FormatDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours  1 -Minutes 45)
FormatDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours  1 -Minutes  1)
FormatDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours  0 -Minutes  1)
```

Sample output:

```
25 hours 45 minutes
1 hour 45 minutes
1 hour 1 minute
0 hours 1 minute
```